# Html / JS - Drawing buttons over canvas

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, flask

I know very little about html, and even less about js. So I want to make a Flask web app to interact with my Raspberry Pi. I want a mjpg stream of my camera and also I want to be able to interact with 2 servos (simple commands; up, down, left, right). So I copied this example of drawing the image, and continuously updating it, changed it a bit, was happy and than I moved on to implementing the buttons. Tried 3-4 methods. They don't appear. I feel like I am missing something basic, but like I said, I know little about the subject. (I thought I could do it from Flask). Here is the code:

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, RESET = "left", "right", "up", "down", "reset"
AVAILABLE_COMMANDS = {
    'Left': LEFT,
    'Right': RIGHT,
    'Up': UP,
    'Down': DOWN,
    'Reset': RESET
}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', commands=AVAILABLE_COMMANDS)

@app.route('/<cmd>')
def command(cmd=None):
    if cmd == RESET:
        camera_command = "X"
        response = "Resetting ..."
    else:
        camera_command = cmd[0].upper()
        response = "Moving {}".format(cmd.capitalize())

    return response, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    app.run(debug = True)
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var url = "static/01.jpg"; //url to load image from
    var refreshInterval = 500; //in ms
    var drawDate = null; //draw date string
    var img;

    function init() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            canvas.setAttribute("width", 640)
            canvas.setAttribute("height", 480)
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            if(drawDate) {
                var now = new Date();
                var text = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
                var maxWidth = 100;
                var x = img.width-10-maxWidth;
                var y = img.height-10;
                context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                context.lineWidth = 2;
                context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
            };
       };
       refresh();
}
function refresh() {
    img.src = url + "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval);
}

</script>
<title>cam_ser</title>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:init();">
<canvas id="canvas"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
{# in index.html #}
{% for label, command in commands.items() %}
    <button class="command command-{{ command }}" value="{{ command }}">
        {{ label }}
    </button>
{% endfor %}

{# and then elsewhere #}
<script>
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var commandButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".command");
    for (var i=0, l=commandButtons.length; i<l; i++) {
        var button = commandButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var clickedButton = e.target;
            var command = clickedButton.value;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onload = function() {
                 alert(request.responseText);
            };
            request.open("GET", "/" + command, true);
            request.send();
        });
    }
}, true);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what's going on. The simple answer is that i need to modify this line:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"/>
```

And that's it. It has nothing to do with the js script. I don't know why i tought it does.

Edit:

It has nothing to do with the js script, but for the image to be displayed correctly you have to match the size of the canvas in js with:

```
canvas.setAttribute("width", 640)
canvas.setAttribute("height", 480)
```